# NullReferenceException when using custom model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I am trying to make a binder for an abstract class. The binder decides which implementation of the class to use.

```
public abstract class Pet
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string species { get; set; }
    abstract public string talk { get; }
}

public class Dog : Pet
{
    override public string talk { get { return "Bark!"; } }
}
public class Cat : Pet
{
    override public string talk { get { return "Miaow."; } }
}
public class Livestock : Pet
{
    override public string talk { get { return "Mooo. Mooo. Fear me."; } }
}
```

So I have a controller which takes a Pet, the binder decides (depending on the species string) if it is a Dog, Cat or Livestock.

```
public class PetBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var values = (ValueProviderCollection)bindingContext.ValueProvider;
        var name = (string)values.GetValue("name").ConvertTo(typeof(string));
        var species = (string)values.GetValue("species").ConvertTo(typeof(string));
        if (species == "dog")
        {
            return new Dog { name = name, species = "dog" };
        }
        else if (species == "cat")
        {
            return new Cat { name = name, species = "cat" };
        }
        else
        {
            return new Livestock { name = name, species = species };
        }
    }
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult WorksFine(Pet pet)
    {
        return Json(pet);
    }

    public JsonResult DoesntWork(List<Pet> pets)
    {
        return Json(pets);
    }
}
```

This works well, but as soon as the pet is in another structure (like `List<Pet>` or another object), I get a NullReferenceException (on the line `var name = (string)values.GetValue("name").ConvertTo(typeof(string));`
 in the PetBinder). What am I doing wrong?

I added a Person class to test. It also gave me a NullReferenceException.

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Pet pet { get; set; }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult PersonAction(Person p)
    {
        return Json(p);
    }
}
```

ccurrens said the reason `var name = (string)values.GetValue("name").ConvertTo(typeof(string));`
 returned null was because it couldn't get the values from a list.

I see they are named `[n].name` and `[n].species` when in a `List<Pet>`, but when in the `Person` object they are named `pet.name` and `pet.species` and when they are in a single `Pet`, they are just named `name` and `species`.

### Solution

To get the parameter names with the right prefix (`[n]` or `pet` or anything else) for `GetValue`, I used the following code:

```
bool hasPrefix = bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName);
string prefix = ((hasPrefix)&&(bindingContext.ModelName!="")) ? bindingContext.ModelName + "." : "";
```

If anyone is interested, I ended up inheriting from `DefaultModelBinder` using something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460081/asp-net-mvc-3-defaultmodelbinder-inheritance-problem/5466824#5466824). Here is the full code I used:

```
public class DefaultPetBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,ModelBindingContext bindingContext,Type modelType)
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460081/asp-net-mvc-3-defaultmodelbinder-inheritance-problem

        bool hasPrefix = bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName);
        string prefix = ((hasPrefix)&&(bindingContext.ModelName!="")) ? bindingContext.ModelName + "." : "";

        // get the parameter species
        ValueProviderResult result;
        result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(prefix+"species");


        if (result.AttemptedValue.Equals("cat"))
            return base.CreateModel(controllerContext,bindingContext,typeof(Cat));
        else if (result.AttemptedValue.Equals("dog"))
            return base.CreateModel(controllerContext,bindingContext,typeof(Dog));
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, typeof(Livestock)); // livestock
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line you're getting your error, `values` could be null or what `GetValue("name")` returns could be null.

I'm assuming when you're calling the `List<Pet>` method, ValueProvider is returning the entire `List` instead of each individual `Pet`, so it can't get the value `"name"` since it doesn't exist in the `List` class.

I can't be more sure without seeing more code.

Comment: Do you mean you would like to see the stack trace? Except for adding the `PetBinder` in Global.asax, there is nothing else.

 I made a Person class with a name and a single `Pet`, and in the debugger I saw that the properties in the ValueProvider were named `pet.name`, so I put `GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".name")`, which returns undefined when in a list (the properties are `[n].name` and `[n].species`)and the right answer in the Person object. How am I supposed to get the properties in a way that works all the time?