# passing the child model to a base model view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this `Model`:

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

This `Controller` method:

```
public ActionResult ChildClassMethod(ChildClass model)
{
        return PartialView("Partials/BaseClassView", model);
}
```

And this `View`:

```
@model BaseClass
```

I get the exception that I'm passing in the wrong model... is there any way for me to make this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3: DefaultModelBinder with inheritance/polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460081/asp-net-mvc-3-defaultmodelbinder-with-inheritance-polymorphism)

Comment: You get the exception when you are passing the model to the view, or when you are passing the values back to the controller?

Comment: What you can try is in "BaseClassView" view do a Html.Action that will return a partial view with a type of childclass

Comment: Passing the `Model` to the `View` throws the exception...I only need the `BaseClass` in the `View`, though the `ChildClass` overrides certain properties of the `BaseClass`. The linkied possible duplicate is actually an unrelated issue and does not apply to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an interface.

```
public ActionResult ChildAction(ChildClass model)
{
    return PartialView("Partials/BaseClassView", model);
}
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{

}
public class BaseClass : IBaseClass
{

}
public interface IBaseClass
{

}
```

View

```
@model IBaseClass
```